# A question about "than"

Tags: comparisons

I want to say

- *We identified a protein molecule ABC, the expression level of which was significantly lower in cell X than (the expression level) in cell Y.*

Is this the correct to omit "the expression level" in ()?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. And you could simplify "the expression level of which was" to *whose expression level was*.

Comment: Simplifying to 'We measured the water, the level of which was higher in the second tank than in the first' it seems fine. [... it was] can obviously be re-inserted. A complication is the arguable treating of 'level' as essentially a single entity (cf 'The river is faster at A than B' / 'The river level is deeper at A than B'  where there is of course only one river, and 'level' is 'quasi-noncount').

Comment: Yes: "in cell Y" is a comparative clause reduced to the PP  functioning as complement of "than". Such clauses are obligatorily reduced in certain ways relative to the structure of main clauses. Here, the comparative clause is reduced to just the PP “in cell x”. We understand "the expression level of protein molecule ABC in cell X was x"; "the expression level of protein molecule ABC in cell Y was y" “x<y”.